# I'm getting a compile time error when appending a string to a const char* in C++?

Tags: c++, string, char

so I'm trying to convert an integer value into a string and then append the string to an already existing const char*. But as mentioned, I'm getting this error:

> error: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type.
>
> ```
>  objDim += objDimStr.c_str();
> ```

Any ideas why?
My code is as follows:

```
    const char* objDim = "The object dimension is: ";
    int objDimension = geo->Dimension();
    std::string objDimStr = std::to_string(objDimension);
    objDim += objDimStr.c_str();
```

Comment: They're addresses, so that's like adding *1428, Elm Street* to *946, Elderberry Road* and expecting Elderberry Road to attach to Elm Street.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objDim` is a *pointer*. When you add to the pointer, you will add to the pointer itself and not append anything to the data it points to.

And you can not add everything to a pointer, basically only integer values. And adding two pointers like you do makes no sense at all (which is why it's not allowed).

If you want to be able to append strings, then use `std::string` for *all* strings.

Besides, that you need to use the `const` qualifier should also give some hints about that what the pointer is pointing to is *constant* and therefore can't be modified (including added to).

---

And in this case you don't need any of the temporary variable `objDimension` or `objDimStr` (unless you use them later in the code):

```
std::string objDim = "The object dimension is: " + std::to_string(geo->Dimension());
```

Here the addition works because there is an [overloaded `operator+` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) that takes the correct arguments in the correct order, and returns a new `std::string` object.

Comment: Okay, but after doing that I will be left with a string. But, I need a const char* type variable to be able to pass it to an API function to display the string on the screen. The function signature is : int RhinoMessageBox ( const char *  message,
const char *  title,
UINT  type 
). So, how do I get a string and then pass it into the function suitably?

Comment: Uhh yeah, that was so simple. I guess I should go through my code first and stop coming here and posting the error. Thanks !

Comment: @Xyber101 No worries. Sometimes it's much to easy to forget such small simple details. :)

Comment: A pointer points to constant chars. The pointer itself can be modified. If concatenation was a standard operation in C++, chances are, one could add more characters past the otherwise constant string.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you were expecting to get a concatenation of strings. No, it's not how it works. `objDim` is but a pointer to a non-modifiable memory area that contains characters. The only possible application of operator `+=` to it that would compile is if you were incrementing it by a few characters:

```
objDim += 11;
std::cout << objDim << '\n'; // prints "dimension is: ";
```

To concatenate strings you can:

1. Either assign the result to a `string` object:

   ```
   std::string result = objDim + objDimStr;
   ```

   (Note the absence of `c_str` anywhere: you cannot sum two pointers, but there's an overload that can prepend a `char` pointer to a `std::string`.)
2. Or give proper type to `objDim`;

   ```
   std::string objDim{"The object dimension is: "};
   objDim += objDimStr;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`objDim` is not an `std::string` but a pointer, so your [concatenation operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) (`+`) which is defined for `std::string` will not work on it.

Define it as an `std::string` and you will be able to use it to concatenate other `std::string`s to it.

Comment: Okay, I perfectly get what you are saying, a string will be appended with a string only, not a pointer. But, I need a char* variable, as that is what I have to pass to an API function to display the string on the screen. The function signature is :  int RhinoMessageBox ( const char *  message,
const char *  title,
UINT  type 
) ?

Comment: @Xyber101:  Then you can do `objDimStr += objDim + objDimStr;`. Then `objDimStr` will contain what you need in the right order.

Comment: Again, that would give me a string wouldn't it? What I need is a char* with the data of the string. How do I do it? Sorry, I am a newbie in C++ and this pointer thing has got me pretty tied up :(

Comment: @Xyber101: `objDimStr.c_str()` will give you what you want. It is the C string equivalent (`const char*`)

Comment: Yeah, thanks :) Thank you so much for your time, P.W !

Answer (score 0):

```
objDim += objDimStr.c_str();
```

Here you add one pointer to other instead of concatenating the string. You need use std::string to concatenate, for example:

```
const char* objDim = "The object dimension is: ";
int objDimension = geo->Dimension();
std::string objDimStr = objDim;
objDimStr += std::to_string(objDimension);
std::cout << objDimStr << std::endl;
```